# Mqtt How a client can get to know that another client is connected or not

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

Hello guys my problem is that I need to keep device(clients) status as they are online or not.

I am connecting through a client id and from subscribing there will topic I can get to know that device is disconnected but if they connect again how can I check they connect again.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The short answer is you don't (at a protocol level).

Publishers and subscribers are totally unaware of each other, messages are sent to topics not to specific subscribing clients.

The slightly longer version:

You could do something with retained messages and LWT (Last Will & Testament)

e.g.

Each client publishes a retained message to the following topic

```
online/<clientID>
```

With a payload of `true` when it connects. It also sets up LWT that will publish a payload of `false` if the client is disconnected by a network fault. If the client cleanly disconnects then it will need to publish the `false` payload as it's last action before going offline.

To tell if client is online you subscribe to the wildcard topic of `online/+` and then check the last segment of the topic for clientid and the payload for the state.