# MQTT know if a client is subscribed (cont)

Tags: mqtt

Today I posted this topic
[MQTT know if a client is subscribed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38917150/mqtt-know-if-a-client-is-subscribed/38917546#38917546)

I would like to try something, but I would like to know if is feasible, may be I'm complicating the things, so if you have another suggestion please feel free

let's suppose that we have the topic **temperature/subscription**

First

Client A subscribes to **subscription** (or in other words **temperature/subscription**)
if he doesn't receive a payload (a retain message)

then

Client A publishes to **subscription** with a payload of **1** or **"online"** as a retain message

and subscribes to the **temperature** topic

Now, Client B

again, subscribes to **subscription** if he receives a payload = someone is already subscribed (Client A)
So, he can't subscribe to **temperature** topic

I still need to add the LWT message, but first I want to start with something simple.

Is it feasible to do this? so I this way I can see if someone is subscribed or not to a topic

Answer (score 0):

As we discussed last time, that will work, but it has a huge gaping timing window between checking for a message on `temperature/subscription` and publishing a message to it to claim the subscription.

Also you need to use the client id of as the marker because retained messages will survive a broker restart, which will disconnect all the client, so client A won't know it still holds the "lock" after a broker restart.

The LWT is only there for is client A crashes and then it will wait for the TTL for the connection to expire before sending the message, you need to explicitly clear that topic if client A disconnects cleanly.

In summary this is a really bad idea, trying to retro fit a concept that MQTT is not suited to.

Comment: understood.. thank you again hardillb, the thing is that i need to find some way to do that, or at least limitate the subscriptions of a channel, that only one can be subscribed :/

Comment: What about the plugin  MQTT Message Log?